# Prove $(0,\infty)$ is equinumerous to $[0, \infty)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think this is the most succinct answer to the set equinumerosity.
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if }x \notin \mathbb{Z},\\
x-1 & \text{if }x \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think you need $1/(2x)$ instead of $1/m$ for the powers of $2$.  Otherwise, it is a good solution.

Comment: Do you mean 1/(2m)?

Comment: $6$ already appears as $f(1/6)$.  It is just the powers of $2$ that need to be replaced.  First, $1/2$ is used, so we need $f(y)=2$.  Then $f(1/4)=2$, so we need $f(1/8)=4,f(1/16)=8,...$.  Or, instead, $f(1/3)=2,f(1/4)=3,f(1/5)=4$.  Make the $f$ values match the previous $x$ value.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; where is my function broken? I thought my second case dealt with the powers of 1/2.

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: This is a rather different question from the one you first asked: it seems rather unfair on the people who have already answered to change the question like this without notification.

Answer (score 0):

A function mapping from $(0,1)$ to $[1,\infty)$:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1&\text{if } x < \frac12\\
\tan(\pi(x-\frac12))+1&\text{else}
\end{cases}$$
That's only surjective, not injective, but the surjection in the other direction is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If surjections are ok, then here's another:

$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{x(x-1)}-4.$$

Comment: @RoryDaulton: The original question was about $(0,1)$ and $[1, \infty)$, so the -3 was correct wrt. the original question.

Comment: @Andre: Oh, I see now, I believe I saw only the later version. Sorry! In my defense, I just *asked* how the supplied answer worked for the question. I'll delete my earlier comments.